The gradient method based attack does not seem make sense for neural networks because the training error is non-convex
There are several gradient-based attack methods. Let $J$ be the training error, then for instance the projected gradient attack is,
$$
\widetilde{x} = \Pi( x + \epsilon  \nabla_x J(\theta, x, y) )
$$
Fast signed gradient method is
$$
\widetilde{x} = x + \epsilon \text{sign}( \nabla_x J(\theta, x, y) )
$$
These methods are all assuming that we are ADDING $\nabla_x J(\theta, x, y)$. This is under the assumption that $\nabla_x J(\theta, x, y)$ points towards the direction of maximum infinitestimal increase of $J$ with respect to $x$.
But this assumption is false, because $J$ is a non-convex function of $x$. So ADDING $\nabla_x J(\theta, x, y)$ does not necessarily produce $\widetilde x$ that yields a larger value of $J$.
Since most of these methods are one-step, therefore there is no guarantee that $\widetilde x$ increases the value of $J$, it might even decrease the value of $J$.
Is there a flaw in my reasoning?

At its core, the attack is really just gradient descent, except we're trying to maximize errors instead of minimize the loss. During training, (S)GD doesn't generally point in the direction of a (global or local) minimum (it can actually be nearly orthogonal from the descent direction), but it can still be an effective optimizer & reduce the loss despite that fact. Same idea here -- getting closer to the goal is good enough.
